# kotlin in android : remove object-value for an Intent,as it is only used once

Tags: android, kotlin

When programming in kotlin one get often code like this, where a value (galleryIntent) needs to be created.

```
        val galleryIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, GALLERY)
```

is there a way to work without this value, like:

```
        Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        .xxxx{startActivityForResult( yyy , GALLERY)}
```

whereas xxxx is a function like 'apply', 'let' ... and yyy is a reference to the Intent

In my humble opinion the code would be much more readable.

Comment: You need activity or fragment context to startActivity. This won't be possible.
Try Anko library if you want a concise code for intents.

Comment: With `let` as xxxxx and `it` as yyy this could work.

Comment: Thank you, yes it worked with let.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing nicely out the answer from Michael Butcher:

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
    .let{startActivityForResult( it , GALLERY)}
```

This for others, who would like to do the same ;-)